# Create a blank HTML page in the Admin Panel I can design with

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, adminhtml, phtml

We are using Magento 1.7.

[image]

In the admin panel I created a dropdown where I have "MYJ Resources" is there a way that when I click on this option I'm redirected to a blank phtml page I can customize with a form on it?

**app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE config>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_MasterCreate>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </Sean_MasterCreate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mastercreate>
                <class>Sean_MasterCreate_Model</class>
            </mastercreate>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <mastercreate>
                <class>Sean_MasterCreate_Block</class>
            </mastercreate>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mastercreate>
                <class>Sean_MasterCreate_Helper</class>
            </mastercreate>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mastercreate>
                    <file>finance.xml</file>
                </mastercreate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mastercreate before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sean_MasterCreate_Adminhtml</mastercreate>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mastercreate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>mastercreate</frontName>
                    <module>Sean_MasterCreate</module>
                </args>
            </mastercreate>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE config>

<config>
    <menu>
        <mastercreate translate="title" module="mastercreate">
            <title>MYJ Tools</title>
            <sort_order>89</sort_order>
            <children>
                <usercreate module="mastercreate">
                    <title>Create Users</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/Creation/createCustomerForm</action>
                </usercreate>
                <productcreate>
                    <title>Create Products</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/Creation/createProductForm</action>
                </productcreate>
                <weightupdate>
                    <title>Update Weights</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/Creation/createWeightForm</action>
                </weightupdate>
                <companyinfo>
                    <title>MYJ Resources</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/Warehouse/createWarehouseForm</action>
                </companyinfo>
            </children>
        </mastercreate>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Here is my controller:
**app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/controllers/Adminhtml/WarehouseController.php**

```
<?php

class Sean_MasterCreate_Adminhtml_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function createWarehouseFormAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mastercreate/adminhtml_warehouse_display')
        );
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session'); //this will allow flash messages
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I create a form using:
**app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/Block/Adminhtml/Warehouse/Display/Form.php**

```
<?php

class Sean_MasterCreate_Block_Adminhtml_Warehouse_Display_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        //Id must be edit_form even if it's a different form
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/warehouse/updateInventory'),
            'method' => 'post'
        ));


        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Here I set display stuff on the page but I want to write as if I were just writing on display.phtml with html and css: **app/code/local/Sean/MasterCreate/Block/Adminhtml/Warehouse/Display.php**

```
<?php

class Sean_MasterCreate_Block_Adminhtml_Warehouse_Display extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'product_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'mastercreate';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_warehouse';
        $this->_mode = 'display';

        $this->setTemplate('finance/action.phtml');

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('mastercreate')->__('MYJ Finance / Inventory');
    }

    //This is automatically tied to where the form action goes/is
    public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/warehouse/updateInventory');
    }
}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/finance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mastercreate_warehouse_createwarehouseform>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="warehouse_display" template="finance/action.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mastercreate_warehouse_createwarehouseform>
</layout>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/finance/action.phtml**

```
<h1> Testing Here </h1>
```

I got it working, I just had to clear the cache however how can I have the phtml file under the header?

[image]

Comment: In your layout file change `../template/finance/action.phtml` to `finance/action.phtml`

Comment: I changed it but still not working quite yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a custom phtml file to admin page

change your controller file action to

```
public function createWarehouseFormAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

add in your module's `layout.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <yourmodule_controller_action>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="block_name" template="path_to_your_template.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </yourmodule_controller_action>
</layout>
```

Comment: How does the module know where to find the layout.xml file? Do I have to follow a certain file path structure?

Comment: I've edited my question with your changes but I think something is wrong still